# Bitcoins being sent to another addres during a transaction

Tags: transactions

I realized a few days back, that if I send some bitcoins to someone, then it shows in blockchain an extra amount sent to my own wallet. So if I send 0.5 BTC from wallet A to B then blockchain shows

```
A--> B 0.5
A-->A  1  (basically sending it to my wallet as well.)
```

Today I noticed a different wallet address during a transaction. So it was like

```
A--> B 0.2
A--> C 0.5
```

Checking address C on blockchain, it gets sent back to A in some time. But since this morning, the bitcoins haven't come back to A. If I open my wallet on multibit, it shows the correct balance. However on blockchain, it's 0.5 less. The funds from C have not been sent back to A, but it shows on multibit the right balance in A.

Comment: See https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your total bitcoin balance consists of the combined total of several addresses. Your wallet contains one, some or many addresses, all of which may have bitcoins on them.

So I think that when inspecting your wallet with a tool like pywallet, you will find that both A and C are there.